# Assigning FrameLayout as half of parent RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a frame layout inside a relative layout, that everything else is positioned below it.
How can I make this frame layout take up one half of the whole screen?

I tried with weight but it doesn't change anything..

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/mainLayoutStyle">

<FrameLayout 
       android:id="@+id/codeLayout"
       style="@style/codeLayoutLargeStyle">   

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/DisplayTextView"
            style="@style/DisplayTextViewLargeStyle"/>
</FrameLayout>
......
.....
   <LinearLayout
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a frame layout inside a relative layout, that everything else is positioned below it

Then you are using wrong layout as your parent. You should replace `RelativeLayout` with `LinearLayout`, set `FrameLayout` heights to `match_parent` and `android:layout_weight="1"` then wrap everyghing that you want below anything needed (Relative, Linear whatever) ensuring it got also set height and layout_weight as above. Then you will get 50%-50% height split

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help.. :/
weird

Comment: Of course it does 50-50 split. you must have done done something wrong. see edited answer.

Comment: ok I can see the image on half of the screen but everything else is messed up..
Give me a few minutes to work it out, maybe you're onto something :)

Comment: Because most likely your whole layout is broken and you i.e. got paddings or offests in `dp` which will result in a mess when we shrink available aread. You need to fix that too but this irrelevant for this question which I was answering - you wanted 50-50 split - and this is how you do it. RelativeLayout and absolute positioning is bad in general so perhaps you should review your layout and clean it up anyway

Answer (score 0):

Weight works only with Linear layout and not with Relative layout

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/mainLayoutStyle"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/codeLayout1"
        style="@style/codeLayoutLargeStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50">   

    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/codeLayout2"
        style="@style/codeLayoutLargeStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50">   

    </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

give each layout height 0dp and weight 50 and give linear layout weight sum of 100

Comment: What it says in crash report

Comment: I have edited my ans and its correct and if it crashes then check for errors problem is something different

Answer (score 0):

Marcin is right, Weight Property will only be effective when you take your parent Layout as Linear Layout and for making your frame layout to cover half screen you have to take two layout as child of that linear layout and divide equal weight.

e.g

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/you_frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00ff00">

</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will helpful to you.